# Newline before closing </pre> might break formatting in other parts of same post

Tags: bug, status-completed, markdown, pre

Adding a newline before *one* of the closing `</pre>`'s might yield missing `<p> .. </p>` tags in other parts of the same post.

Things seem to be formatted fine if the *first* closing `</pre>` is on a new line by itself, or if *all* closing `</pre>`'s are on the last line of their `<pre>` blocks. But if the first closing `</pre>` is at the end of the last line, then using a closing `</pre>` on a new line somewhere later, messes up the text above it, a bit.

Example output ([source](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/363e0e45-594f-428a-8c17-57d9a95b7f22/view-source)):

---

```
Some text in <pre>, closing </pre> on the last line, causing some of the
following paragraphs to merge into one. Editing this pre-formatted block to
put the closing </pre> on a new line by itself, will fix the formatting of
those paragraphs, also in the preview.
```

Line, surrounded by blank lines. Should be a new paragraph followed by whitespace.

Another line, surrounded by blank lines. Should be a yet another new paragraph.

```
More text in <pre>, closing </pre> on the next line. When NOT changing the
closing </pre> of the previous pre-formatted block, then putting the closing
</pre> of THIS very pre-formatted block onto its last line, will also fix
the formatting of the paragraphs above.
```

Line, surrounded by blank lines. Should be a new paragraph followed by whitespace.

Fourth line, surrounded by blank lines. Should be a new paragraph again.

---

The above currently renders the lines following the first `<pre>` block without any `<p>` tags at all:

[image]

This question originally was an "answer" (not so much) at [Preview should match the posted view](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1227/preview-should-match-the-posted-view/29085#29085). In its comments Jeff already found that this is [indeed a bug](http://is.gd/5yuJ1) in the original Perl version of Markdown and all descendants. **It's not a big deal for me**, so I'm just posting it here for future reference. Please just mark it as "won't fix". (I ran into it in [revision 1](https://superuser.com/revisions/67880/list) at [some answer](https://superuser.com/questions/66082/why-do-russian-characters-in-some-received-emails-change-when-reading-in-david/67880#67880) at Super User.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, it might be fixable, because per the babelmark link, it is fixed in markdown.pl 1.0.2b8.

There is a new block-level HTML detection algorithm in markdown.pl 1.0.2b8 compared to markdown 1.0.1 but I haven't ported that across yet. I kind of suspect that's the fix.

I'll try to get to that..

edit: I incorporated the latest [MarkdownSharp](http://code.google.com/p/markdownsharp/) and indeed the new block detection algorithm fixes this.