# Is it possible to use <sub>HTML</sub> in question titles?

Tags: support, design, title

I found [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5220046/write-text-with-coefficient-like-c-c-c-on-label) (screenshot [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rBeZl.png)) where the user placed some subscript characters both in title and body.

The weird thing is the title displays them correctly, but the body won't, so I changed them to `<sub>1</sub>` and so on.

Now I'm wondering: is it possible to use the allowed HTML tags in the title, or not? (I don't want to try doing it as I fear to mess it up, and I don't have editing privilege so test edits will waste someone's time.)

Comment: That has been done using UTF. You can enable compose key and generate numerical subscripts/superscripts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's possible, but it won't render as such. So if you put `<i>` or `<li>` in a title (without the code backticks, that is), it won't render in the title as italic or a list item. That lets you, among other things, ask about those elements. I've demonstrated exactly such in the title of this question.

There used to be an issue in which [auto-generated titles would render the HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PeLv3.png) even though the question title proper did not. As noted by balpha below, this will be fixed in the upcoming build.

Comment: that autogenerated thing needs some fixin' :)

Comment: ... and fixed (next build)

Comment: @balpha, now the title "Newline before closing </pre> might break formatting in other parts of same post" is rendered without the `</pre>` part altogether. Is that by design? (See [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74754/unbalanced-blank-lines-after-inline-html-comments-might-break-formatting) just above the "Update".)

Comment: @Arjan: this is about *autogenerated* link texts for bare question links. You entered the text by hand, including an (unencoded) </pre> that will get stripped

Comment: Aha, @balpha, of course! Sorry about the alert! :-)