# Also let shortlinks in comments have a tooltip with the question title

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, comments, hyperlinks, tooltips

See the two comments below for an example.  The first comment has the title of the linked question in the tooltip, but the second link does not.

Comment: You mean like one of these? - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82146/also-let-shortlinks-in-comments-have-a-tooltip-with-the-question-title

Comment: Or one of these? http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/82146/2598

Comment: (I think I see what you mean)

Comment: I like this except for one case -- I use the short links sometimes in situations where I'm linking to a deleted question and I specifically *don't* want to reveal the title. If that isn't a significant enough case to not do this for deleted questions, I think I'd be okay with that.

Comment: @Jon, but then just leave the title out: the tooltip is really based on whatever one types. It's NOT the actual title of the post one is linking to. Like: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82146/this-is-this-very-question-but-not-the-real-title

Comment: @Jon Even if you use that, clicking on the link will redirect you to a version that has the slug, even if you don't have permission to view deleted questions. They won't be able to see the content, but the title will be just as visible in the end.

Comment: @Grace, I never knew that, but you're very right, and it also applies to the full blown `/questions/` URL: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45118/not-the-real-title-of-a-deleted-question (which *you* can see, being 10k+, but I cannot).

Comment: Well, withdrawing my objection since I'm clearly inobservant. lol thanks guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tooltip is simply created from the URL. The short link being as short as possible, there's currently not enough information to create the `title` attribute.

See the comments below in action, which use:

> /questions/82146/also-let-shortlinks-in-comments-have-a-tooltip-with-the-question-title
> /questions/82146/this-is-this-very-question-but-not-the-real-title

That aside: I really don't see *why* folks would use the short links on these sites themselves. I actually think many don't know that [these are referral links](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74274/privacy-leak-in-permalink) (which are only [useful](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/announcer-booster-and-publicist-badges/) when used on third-party sites) and *accidentally* use those rather than the long links...

Comment: Hover and see the `title` attribute as the tooltip: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82146/also-let-shortlinks-in-comments-have-a-tooltip-with-the-question-title and
http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82146/this-is-this-very-question-but-not-the-real-title

Comment: I suppose it would be an easy, yet time consuming, call to the API for each link to get the title of the question.

Comment: I think some people equally use them not because they are unaware, but they are fully aware and expect that it can contribute towards the publicity badges. Also, short links probably allow people to fit more links, given the character limit.

Comment: @jjnguy, I guess you're right about performance; for some reason [automatic titles](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49433/replace-trilogy-raw-links-with-the-current-question-title/69483#69483) for plain links in normal posts are also determined when a post is saved, not when it's rendered. (And hence the automatic title does not reflect later changes, unless the referring post is edited after the change.) But: I'm just assuming this.

Comment: Some changes were made about the automatic titles, actually (courtesy [balpha](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80543/can-we-improve-the-automatic-titling-of-links-to-internal-urls/80546#80546), though I see you already knew that). The editor preview now does render the title, and recently it was updated to no longer render HTML as HTML. I don't have a sample of a scenario of when a title has changed since the posting, though, so I don't know if it updates for that yet. But it's not entirely at post submission anymore, at least.

Comment: @Grace, [the very feature request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49433/replace-trilogy-raw-links-with-the-current-question-title/) for the automatic links (last edited May 2010) still has a bare link in it, which nowadays (and when you click the "edit" link") would be replaced. That somehow tells me the links are still replaced when saving a post? And what does "to no longer render HTML as HTML" mean?

Comment: Ah, good point there. As for the later point, it used to render things like `<i>` or `<sub>` (without backticks, of course) in titles as if they were legal HTML. See [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82013/is-it-possible-to-use-subhtml-sub-in-question-titles/82017#82017).

Comment: I actually use shortlinks because of their, well, _shortness_, but then again I usually forget to remove the referral part... But since the link title is _not_ determined by the actual question but only by the title given in the long link, this request will probably be declined or bydesign