# Formatting bug causing code to not show up

Tags: bug, status-completed, syntax-highlighting, markdown-preview

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Unbalanced blank lines after inline HTML comments might break formatting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74754)

In this post: [Formatting Sandbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox/83216#83216)
the preview shows code (stuff indented 4 spaces), while the regular page does not. Here's the text of the post (originally from a question I was editing on SO):

```
i wrote sending email function that only work my debug mode(debug local server) when i publishing and hosting C# code that function not work. this my email configuration function

<!-- language: lang-xml -->
    <configuration>
        <system.net>
            <mailSettings>
                <smtp from="admin@XXXX.com">
                    <network host="smtp.XXXXX.com" port="25"
                             userName="admin@XXXXX.com" password="XXXXX" />
                </smtp>
            </mailSettings>
        </system.net>
        <appSettings/>
        <connectionStrings/>
        <system.web>
```

I discovered that if I put a blank line after the "language" comment then everything works.

It looks like this is maybe the issue reported at [Unbalanced blank lines after inline HTML comments might break formatting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74754/unbalanced-blank-lines-after-inline-html-comments-might-break-formatting)

Answer (score 1):

While having the preview be different than the final post is a bug, the preview code is at fault.

Otherwise the result is as expected.

(1) Markdown strips out most HTML and (2) code must be indented at least 4 spaces and follow a blank line.

Since `<!-- language: lang-xml -->` wasn't indented, it was treated as HTML.

Since everything after it didn't follow a blank line, it was not recognized as a code block.

But the preview rendered incorrectly and didn't show that the indented HTML would be stripped.

Comment: The HTML comment is not supposed to be indented: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63800/interface-options-for-specifying-language-prettify/81970#81970 It is a way to tell the prettifier how to colorize the code that follows it.

Comment: Yes, but in that answer, notice that the following code has a blank line preceding it.

Comment: I'm not arguing that a blank line shouldn't precede it; I'm arguing that if a blank line *doesn't* precede it, the text should still show up (possibly not as *code*), and the preview should look like the page.

Comment: No, if the blank line doesn't precede it, the text -- which is XML/HTML code -- should **NOT** show up -- as the final post shows correctly.  But, yes, the preview should look like the posted page.

Comment: I see, you're saying that it's actually the preview that's wrong. I'm fine with that.