# Differences in preview-vs-live rendering with <!-- language -->

Tags: bug, status-completed, markdown, markdown-preview

I noticed that, while typing out a question, the [`<!-- language -->`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63800/interface-options-for-specifying-language-prettify/81970#81970) specifier caused different rendering in the question preview than when I published the question.

Specifically, omitting the new line between the `<!-- ... -->` and the code caused the code to be rendered as though it wasn't indented (ie, the HTML was interpreted).

After I'd asked the question, the following rendered as "**Bold**":

```
<!-- language:html -->
    <b>Bold</b>
```

while the following rendered as `<b>Bold<b>`:

```
<!-- language:html -->

    <b>Bold</b>
```

However, *both* of them rendered as `<b>Bold</b>` in the preview below the new-question form, and it wasn't until I'd asked the question that I realized my HTML wasn't going to be escaped.

Comment: Hmm... Pretty sure that's a dupe, but I can't find the original

Comment: @balpha Neither could I. I couldn't think of what else it might be tagged with, so I invented the `language-specifier` tag. Please retag if there is something more appropriate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is now fixed, per:

[Unbalanced blank lines after inline HTML comments might break formatting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74754/unbalanced-blank-lines-after-inline-html-comments-might-break-formatting)

The preview should also correctly reflect the final output.