# <!-- summary --> now leaves a blank paragraph on top of the About Me section

Tags: bug, status-completed, markdown, user-card

When I first included a summary in my profile for use with my [user card popup](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104810/how-does-the-user-card-popup-work), using this syntax:

```html
<!-- summary: A short summary of myself goes here! -->

### Heading

Full About Me bio... (whether it starts with a heading or not is irrelevant)
```

My About Me section looked like this:

[image: Before]

Which was fine and all. Well, I just updated my bio, and it now looks like this:

[image: After]

That extra padding on top of the About Me box appears to be an empty `<p></p>`. Is it because of the `<!-- summary -->` comment?

For the record, removing one blank line doesn't help:

```html
<!-- summary: A short summary of myself goes here! -->
### Heading

Full About Me bio...
```

And if I put the first line of my full bio on the same line as the summary, the empty paragraph disappears but then I lose formatting of things like headings:

```html
<!-- summary: A short summary of myself goes here! -->### Not a heading anymore

Full About Me bio...
```

Comment: I'm not sure if it's been reported here before, but the same issue happens when I add a language-all hint to the top of a post; an empty `<p></p>` appears in its place.

Comment: As a temporary work around, you *can* put the summary at the end, and it'll still work.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This was my fault; it's [fixed in the next build](http://code.google.com/p/markdownsharp/source/detail?r=d10d338032f619829226211d1021446b0eb18c2d). In [this recent bugfix](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1828/the-preview-of-the-post-doesnt-match-how-the-post-is-rendered-when-saved/2388#2388), I forgot to consider HTML comments that start at the beginning of the text, i.e. aren't really preceded by newlines.

Since Markdown has the concept of "block-level HTML comments" (which is something I like to [bitch about](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/95987/html-comment-containing-url-breaks-if-followed-by-another-html-comment/96002#96002), but actually helps us here), here's what *should* happen:

- **Markdown Source**

  ```html
  <!-- foo: bar -->

  some text
  ```
- **Rendered HTML**

  ```html
  <!-- foo: bar -->

  <p>some text</p>
  ```
- **Sanitized HTML**

  ```html
  <p>some text</p>
  ```

With the broken recognition of block-level comments at the beginning of the text, here's what happened instead:

- **Markdown Source**

  ```html
  <!-- foo: bar -->

  some text
  ```
- **Rendered HTML**

  ```html
  <p><!-- foo: bar --></p>

  <p>some text</p>
  ```
- **Sanitized HTML**

  ```html
  <p></p>

  <p>some text</p>
  ```

Ironically, to work around this issue until the next build, you can just add two newlines at the top of the post.