# > is closing HTML comments without a -​- delimiter

Tags: support, markdown, design

If I try to put something like this into a question or answer

```
<!-- <br>s are important here -->
```

the first `>` after the "br" is matched to the first `<` before the "!--", resulting in this being displayed:

> s are important here -->

This happens in both previews and actual posts. I'd say it's a bug.  HTML comments shouldn't be treated as regular HTML tags; `<!--` should only be matched to `-->`.

Comment: So what you're saying is that `>` is ending your *HTML comment* even though only `-->` should end your HTML comment, as explained [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/intro/sgmltut.html#h-3.2.4)? In other words, `<!-- this is a comment -->` and `<!-- this is a comment >` are being rendered identically (hidden) even though the latter isn't a valid HTML comment?

Comment: @Chris: hmm, I think yes, exactly. Look [here](http://jsfiddle.net/MmbUG/), you'll see that html isn't broken by > there

Comment: @Chris: no, actually I  need to use >--> in order to break it (to terminate the comment).  Look at my last edit

Comment: @Martin Could you edit that back into your question? It sounds like a lot of folks are getting confused about the difference between HTML comments, Stack Overflow comments, and HTML comments in Stack Overflow comments. You're talking about HTML comments in Stack Overflow questions and answers.

Comment: @Chris: Feel free to edit it back, because I'm not sure what should I edit back

Comment: @MatthewRead: Glad you got it now :)

Comment: @Martin: **This is not a bug.** Please do not add that tag in.

Comment: @animuson: yes, that's a bug. HTML comment is being malformed by adding >

Comment: @AdamRackis: It doesn't matter. I didn't say that team should fix it. It is a bug, so I reported it.

Comment: Stop adding the bug tag, this isn't one. HTML comments are not among the allowed HTML tags and get removed. Conveniently, this looks like they were treated as comments, but they're not.

Comment: @balpha: I didn't add one for 14 minutes, because I wanted to wait for *you*

Comment: Can we have a better markdown-ish way to specify language formatting then? `<!-- language: lang-foo -->` is such a pain to type. How about `[lang:foo]`?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[It looks like](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/95374/154510) this is [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign):

> It should be mentioned that while a `>` is a valid character in a comment from both the W3C specification and the above Regex, it's not going to work correctly in our Markdown, because the tag sanitizer will eat it:
>
> `<!-- love > hate -->`
>
> turns into
>
> `hate -->`

Personally I would not expect the tag sanitizer to take precedence over this, but it's not my call.

Answer (score 13):

The short answer, according to [balpha ♦](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/115866/balpha), appears to be that *Stack Exchange does not support HTML comments in Markdown*: it only supports [a very strict subset of HTML](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/1777/162705). You may be able to put HTML comments in your posts, and they may be hidden in the rendered output, but they're not really guaranteed to work.

Comment: So the fact that HTML comments produce invisible content in an SO post is merely a by-product of the fact that it's being parsed as an (invalid) HTML tag, and not an HTML comment?

Comment: @Madmartigan That's the way I interpret it.

Comment: So then `<!-- this -->` gets interpreted as a "`!-- this --`" HTML tag, and it's invalid so it's just not displayed? Just like if you used `<hello this is a "comment">` to hide text? Looks like the fact that HTML comments work in the first place is the only "bug" then...

Comment: @Mad Except for a very few occasions where they're (ab)used as metadata containers (e.g. specifying the language for the syntax highlighter), yes, it's a byproduct of being considered invalid.

Comment: I've always used this `<!-- -->` to break up a code block into two parts (same language in both blocks), I guess I could have used `<anything>`. I suppose this is the source of all the confusion then.

Answer (score 5):

You cannot use HTML comments anywhere here on Stack Exchange. Comments such as `<!-- filler -->` are sometimes used in answers and questions to bypass character limits, but **get removed in the final output**. Only some HTML is allowed in posts, the rest all gets filtered out.

If you think this should be allowed, you need to fill out a **detailed reason** why you think you should be able to do this, file a feature request, and let the community downvote it into oblivion.

As per your example, it is finding the `<!-- <br>` first because the Markdown system **doesn't care about your HTML comment**. They're not allowed, so it doesn't search for the closing `-->`. It just sees that `<!-- <br>` looks like an HTML element, it's not allowed, and thus it gets removed.

**Actual HTML source:**

```
<pre><code>The first one &lt;!-- this is the comment --&gt; the second one &lt;!-- this is the second comment &gt;--&gt;
</code></pre>
<hr>
<h3>Result</h3>
<hr>
<p>Result: The first one  the second one --></p>
```

Notice the lack of actual, physical HTML comments in the source of the document.

Comment: Look at the edited post. I actually don't want to show the code for comment, I want to actually make it a HTML comment

Comment: @MatthewRead: I know about `&lt;`, `&gt;`, but I actually want to hide the comment from the normal reader

Comment: Where do you get the idea that HTML comments aren't allowed in posts (as actual, invisible HTML comments)? They are. I use them quite frequently to break up two blocks of code or to leave a note to would-be editors.

Comment: @Madmartigan: Look at the source. Do you see any actual comments in the HTML? They're in the post when you click edit, but **they don't show up in the actual output**.

Comment: You said "the Markdown system doesn't care about your HTML comment. They're not allowed"

Comment: @Madmartigan: They're not. They get removed. That seems very not-allowed-ish to me.

Comment: They don't get removed, what do you mean? We're not talking about the *actual* source code of the page, that's irrelevant. Guys: Are we talking about putting HTML comments in "Comments on a post, like right here" or in the actual post body? Looks very much to me like OP is asking about how this works *in an actual SO post*.

Comment: @AdamRackis If I understand Martin correctly, he's talking about putting HTML comments in *questions and answers*.

Comment: @Chris: yeah, that's it

Comment: I have no idea why this gets downvoted into oblivion. This is the correct answer.

Comment: @balpha - I'm glad I'm not the only one thinking that.  This is a bug only by the most narrow, meaningless criteria.  Comments are not displayed.  Putting certain things in comments breaks things?  Then don't do that.  There's no use case for you to ever need to do that.

Comment: @Martin - because the inability to enter something—which is already not allowed—in certain formats isn't really a bug.