# Backticks in HTML comments in markdown

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

```
 foo
 <!--  `hello` -->
 bar
```

Gives:

foo
  -->
 bar

Annoying when you want to temporarily comment out code.

Comment: Hi! Looks like you are trying to temporarily comment out code.  Need some help with that?

Comment: @Lix: [] DONT SHOW THIS AGAIN ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is expected.

HTML comments aren't supported by Stack Exchange system!

Take a look at this [related](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120415/is-closing-html-comments-without-a-delimiter) bug report (which was silently declined/confirmed as [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign)

Comment: Stupid....@#@&*.. MSO...system..not..letting..me...accept...will..have...to..wait...two..minutes....GARR! (Why does MSO have the "accept"ing restriction anyways?)

Comment: Hi! Looks like you're trying to accept an a... Ugg... now I've started annoying myself too :/