# Bug in markdown parser - Horizontal line parser

Tags: bug, status-completed, markdown, markdown-preview

### Symptoms

The following input causes stackexchange page to freeze (give it a try :P)

```
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - a
```

### Cause

This is caused by a **Catastrophic Backtracking** in the horizontal lines regexes. The responsible code should be something like this:

```
var replacement = "<hr />\n";
text = text.replace(/^[ ]{0,2}([ ]?\*[ ]?){3,}[ \t]*$/gm, replacement);
text = text.replace(/^[ ]{0,2}([ ]?-[ ]?){3,}[ \t]*$/gm, replacement);
text = text.replace(/^[ ]{0,2}([ ]?_[ ]?){3,}[ \t]*$/gm, replacement);
```

### Fix

In order to fix this, the regexes can be simplified:

```
/^( ?-){3,}[ \t]*$/gm
```

### Related post

[Regex to parse horizontal rules in Markdown](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/150277/why-is-this-regex-so-painfully-slow-in-certain-conditions)

Comment: Wow, you broke my Chrome...

Comment: @Cai nah, only one tab. :)

Comment: @Sha actually crashed all SE tabs the first time, then crashed the whole window the second time :)

Comment: Very very related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/95256/possible-dos-with-html-comments-in-questions-and-answers/

Answer (score 7):

Good thing I tested this out in a separate browser. :)

Used your regex with a small modification to preserve leading spaces that we currently allow in front of horizontal rules. The fix will go out with the next prod build. Thanks!

Comment: Shameless pug: Ever considered using a newer version of https://github.com/showdownjs/showdown ?
It improved a lot since the fork

Comment: Obviously, that should be read as Shameless Pub, not Pug! lol