# Incorrect Markdown preview of list items after a header

Tags: bug, status-completed, markdown, list

A picture says more than thousand words. Look:

[image]

It's just in the preview. When I submit the post, it get Markdown'ed correctly. This has worked fine yesterday. I use this construct very often for the list of "See also" links.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I made a [change yesterday](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74754/unbalanced-blank-lines-after-inline-html-comments-might-break-formatting/95375#95375) to make the server and the client versions of Markdown behave more similarly in certain cases, but I missed a piece, so in this case I caused the opposite :)

Fixed after the next build.

Comment: Fix confirmed @ meta and SO. Thanks (that took a while though :) ).