# Bullets don't work right under headings

Tags: bug, status-completed, markdown-preview

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Incorrect Markdown preview of list items after a header](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/95426/incorrect-markdown-preview-of-list-items-after-a-header)

The first Markdown bullet under a heading doesn't actually appear as a bullet in the preview when writing/editing a post.

### For example:

- this should be a bullet
- but only the second one actually shows a bullet

It looks fine here, but if you look at [this post's preview](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/95586/edit), it's broken:

[image: screenshot]

Users in the comments report [it was more broken yesterday](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/95426/incorrect-markdown-preview-of-list-items-after-a-header), but it looks like *balpha* might have missed a spot.

Comment: It should be a bullet, and it actually is!

Comment: @Bavarious:  Yeah, it's just the previews that are screwed up.  Edited now.  (This post also was partly to test whether that was the case.  :-)

Comment: Yup; I think it’s the same issue with the revision history. There’s a duplicate question somewhere.

Comment: @Tim:  Bah!  In my defense, it's slightly less broken now than it was then.

Comment: @Patches I think that's just because of the newline you have between the two bullets. But yeah, hopefully it should be `[status-completed]` in a more visible way soon. :)

Comment: @Tim:  Oh yeah, that's it.  In my experience double newlines are required in a lot of places to get proper formatting so I just assumed that was [by-design].

Comment: This is indeed the same issue, and it's fixed with the same fix. That fix just isn't deployed yet.

Comment: ... *now* it is :)